# Read json config files during karma unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I've mostly got my unit tests working but I'm getting stuck when the application tries to load some JSON files from the app directory. I get an error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET scripts/config/getSomeConfig.json
```

I could use `$httpBackend.whenGET().respond()` but I would prefer the application to load the file instead.

**My karma.conf.js looks like this**

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'app/',
      moduleName: 'html5App'
    },
files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'bower_components/ionic/js/ionic.js',
      'bower_components/ionic/js/ionic-angular.js',
      'bower_components/ng-lodash/build/ng-lodash.js',
      'app/lib/**/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.html',
      'app/scripts/**/*.json',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
```

I have also tried using the ng-html2js preprocessor the same way I use it for html files (which work fine by the way).

```
preprocessors: {
      'app/scripts/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
      'app/scripts/**/*.json': ['ng-html2js']
    },
```

The latter successfully converts the files to json.js but they are still not being read by karma.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: "the application tries to load some JSON files from the app directory" - but you know the code in you app that does this call, right? so you can either patch with $httpBackend or make conditional?

Comment: @shershen $httpBackend would mean I copy the response to the $httpBackend function call, no? What does "make conditional" mean?

Comment: Can u try using json_fixtures. This how we have added in our project.
 var preprocessors = {
        'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
        'src/test-data/**/*.json': ['json_fixtures']
    };

    pathSrcHtml.forEach(function (path) {
        preprocessors[path] = ['ng-html2js'];
    });